# Python dependency hell: A compromise between virtualenv and global dependencies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependency-management

I've tested various ways to **manage my project dependencies** in Python so far:

1. Installing everything global with pip (saves spaces, but sooner or later gets you in trouble)
2. pip & venv or virtualenv (a bit of a pain to manage, but ok for many cases)
3. pipenv & pipfile (a little bit easier than venv/virtualenv, but slow and some vendor-lock, virtual envs hide somewhere else than the actual project folder)
4. conda as package and environment manager (great as long as the packages are all available in conda, mixing pip & conda is a bit hacky)
5. Poetry - I haven't tried this one
6. ...

My problem with all of these (except 1.) is that my harddrive space fills up pretty fast: I am not a developer, I use Python for my daily work. Therefore, I have hundreds of small projects that all do their thing. Unfortunately, for 80% of projects I need the "big" packages: `numpy`, `pandas`, `scipy`, `matplotlib` - you name it. A typical small project is about 1000 to 2000 lines of code, but has 800MB of package dependencies in venv/virtualenv/pipenv. *Virtually* I have about 100+ GB of my HDD filled with python virtual dependencies.

Moreover, installing all of these in each virtual environment takes time. I am working in Windows, many packages cannot be easily installed from pip in windows: `Shapely`, `Fiona`, `GDAL` - I need the precompiled wheels from [Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/). This is easy, but it breaks most workflows (e.g. `pip install -r requirements.txt` or `pipenv install` from pipfile). I feel like I am 40% installing/updating package dependencies and only 60% of my time writing code. Further, none of these package managers really help with publishing & testing code, so I need other tools e.g. `setuptools`, `tox`, `semantic-release`, `twine`...

I've talked to colleagues but they all face the same problem and no one seems to have a real solution. I was wondering if there is an approach to have some packages, e.g. the ones you use in most projects, installed globally - for example, `numpy`, `pandas`, `scipy`, `matplotlib` would be installed with pip in `C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages` or with `conda` in `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages` - these are well developed packages that don't often break things. And if, I would like to fix that anyway soon in my projects.

Other things would go in local virtualenv-folders - I am tempted to move my current workflow from `pipenv` to `conda`.

Does such an approach make sense at all? At least there has been a lot of development lately in python, perhaps something emerged that I didn't see yet.
Is there any best-practice guidance on how to setup files in such a mixed global-local environment, e.g. how to maintain `setup.py`, `requirements.txt` or `pyproject.toml` for sharing development projects through Gitlab, Github etc.? What are the pitfalls/caveats?

There's also [this great blog post](https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2018/07/17/pipenv-promises-a-lot-delivers-very-little/) from Chris Warrick that explains it pretty much fully.

**[Update 2020]**

After half a year, I can say that working with Conda ([Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)) has solved most of my problems:

- it runs on every system, WSL, Windows, native Linux etc. `conda env create -f myenv.yml` is the same on every platform
- most packages are already available on conda-forge, it is easy to get own packages accepted on conda-forge
- for those packages not on conda, I can install `pip` in conda environment and add packages from pypi with pip. Hint: `conda update --all -n myenv -c conda-forge` will only update packages from conda, not those installed with `pip`. Pip installed dependencies must be updated manually with `pip install pack_name --upgrade`. Note that installing packages with pip in conda is an emergency solution that should typically be [avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475042/python-dependency-hell-a-compromise-between-virtualenv-and-global-dependencies#comment96050647_54625714)
- I can create strict or open `environment.yml`, specifying the conda channel priority, the packages from conda and the packages from pip
- I can create conda environments from those ymls in a single statement, e.g. to setup a dev environment in Gitlab Continuous Integration, using the `Miniconda3 Docker` - this makes test-runs very simple and straight forward
- package versions in `yml`s can be defined strict or open, depending on the situation. E.g. you can fix the env to Python 3.6, but have it retrieve any security updates in this version-range (e.g. 3.6.9)
- I found that conda solves almost all problems with c-compiled dependencies in Windows; conda env's in Windows do allow [freezing](https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze) python code into an executable (tested!) that can be distributed to Windows end-users who cannot use package managers for some reason.
- regarding the issue with "big dependencies": I ended up creating many specific (i.e. small) and a few unspecific (i.e. big) conda environments: For example, I have a quite big `jupyter_env`, where jupyter lab and most of my scientific packages are installed (numpy, geos, pandas scipy etc.) - I activate it whenever I need access to these tools, I can keep those up to date in a single place. For development of specific packages, I have extra environments that are only used for the package-dependencies (e.g. `packe1_env`). I have about 10 environemnts overall, which is manageable. Some general purpose tools are installed in the base conda environment, e.g. `pylint`. Be warned: to make pylint/pycodestyle/autopep8 etc. work (e.g.) in VS Code, it must be installed to the same env that contains the python-code-dependencies - otherwise, you'll get unresolved import warnings
- I installed **mini**conda with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) package manager for windows. I keep it up to date with `conda update -n base conda`, and my envs with `conda update --all -n myenv -c conda-forge` once a week, works like a charm!
- **New Update:** there's a `--stack` flag available (as of [2019-02-07](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#463-2019-02-07)) that allows stacking conda environments, e.g. `conda activate my_big_env` then `conda activate --stack dev_tools_env` allows making some general purpose packages available in many envs. However, use with caution - I found that code linters, such as pylint, must be in the same env as the dependencies of the code that is linted
- **New Update 2**: I started using `conda` from `Windows Subsystem for Linux` (WSL), this improved again my workflow significantly: packages are installed faster, I can work with VS Code Insiders in Windows directly connected to WSL and there're far less bugs with python packages in the Linux environment.
- **Another Update** on a side note, the [Miniconda Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda/) allows converting local conda env workflows flawlessly into containerized infrastructure (CI & CD), tested this for a while now and pretty happy with it - the Dockerfile is cleaner than with Python Docker because conda manages more of the dependency work than pip does. I use this nowadays more and more, for example, when working with jupyter lab, which is started from within a container.
- yes, I stumbled into compatibility problems between certain packages in a conda env, but very rarely. There're two approaches: if it is an important env that must work stable, enable `conda config --env --set channel_priority strict` - this will only install versions that are compatible. With very few and rare package combinations, this may result in unsolvable dependency conflicts (i.e. the env cannot be created). In this case, I usually create smaller envs for experimental development, with less packages and `channel_priority` set to `flexible` (the default). Sometimes, package subsets exists that are easier to solve such as `geoviews-core` (instead of `geoviews`) or `matplotlib-base` (instead of `matplotlib`). It's also a good approach to try lower python versions for those experimental envs that are unsolvable with `strict`, e.g. `conda create -n jupyter_exp_env python=3.6 -c conda-forge`. A last-resort hack is installing packages with pip, which avoids conda's package resolver (but may result in unstable environments and other issues, you've been warned!). Make sure to explicitly install `pip` in your env first.
- One overall drawback is that conda gets kind of slow when using the large conda-forge channel. They're [working on it](https://medium.com/@wolfv/making-conda-fast-again-4da4debfb3b7), but at the same time conda-forge index is growing really fast.

**[Update 2021]**

Since this post still gets many views, here is a subjective 2021 update:

- if you are in data science, (mini)[conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) is still worth a look
- otherwise, [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) and the `pyproject.toml` seem to be the common agreed upon denominator

**[Update 2023]**

I am slowly moving away from conda. `pip`+`venv` seem to be the more viable option and it frequently works better and faster (e.g. pytorch, transformers). Forget Windows: pip only works well in WSL/Linux. For package maintainers, `setuptools>64` now allows `pyproject.toml`-only based packages, finally a unified packaging experience! Get rid of your `setup.py`'s..

Comment: If internet usage is not an issue, you can look into working directly on google colab notebooks, or else you the method that you already talk about will be best

Comment: Always use a generic Python tag for Python questions

Comment: "mixing pip & conda is a bit hacky" you could use `conda` virtual envs and install everything inside using `pip`? (although I - perhaps ignorantly - don't know why mixing would cause issues)

Comment: Yes, but then again I am facing the problem that I need to install everything in the conda virtual env, which takes up too much space. Also, I don't know how to update requirements.txt or getting cx_freeze correct under such a mixed pip/conda env

Comment: Consider using btrfs or zfs, which both support block-level deduplication of the filesystem.

Comment: @Score_Under Even just hard linking together the read only files would be enough.

Comment: Thanks - worth a try, although this sounds a bit like the hacky road I was following so far. Good to know at least that there doesn't seem to be an alternative available that I was missing

Comment: I agree with the amount of work needed to get everything working...
For **pipenv**, you set the environment variable `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` to true, then `pipenv` creates the virtual environment in your project directory (`.venv` as default)

Comment: and there is still a hell from python version, v3.6, v3.10 and the old v2.7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Problem**

You have listed a number of issues that no one approach may be able to completely resolve:

- *space*

> 'I need the "big" packages: numpy, pandas, scipy, matplotlib... Virtually I have about 100+ GB of my HDD filled with python virtual dependencies'

- *time*

> ... installing all of these in each virtual environment takes time

- *publishing*

> ... none of these package managers really help with publishing & testing code ...

- *workflow*

> I am tempted to move my current workflow from pipenv to conda.

Thankfully, what you have described is not quite the classic dependency problem that plagues package managers - circular dependencies, pinning dependencies, versioning, etc.

---

**Details**

I have used conda on Windows many years now under similar restrictions with reasonable success.  Conda was originally designed to make installing scipy-related packages easier. It still does.

If you are using the "scipy stack" (scipy, numpy, pandas, ...), conda is your most reliable choice.

Conda **can**:

- install scipy packages
- install C-extensions and non-Python packages (needed to run numpy and other packages)
- integrate conda packages, conda channels (you should look into this) and pip to access packages
- dependency separation with virtual environments

Conda **can't**:

- help with publishing code

---

*Reproducible Envs*

The following steps should help reproduce virtualenvs if needed:

- Do not install scipy packages with pip.  I would rely on conda to do the heavy lifting.  It is much faster and more stable.  You can pip install less common packages inside conda environments.
- On occasion, a pip package may conflict with conda packages within an environment (see [release notes](https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/) addressing this issue).

*Avoid pip-issues*

> I was wondering if there is an approach to have some packages, e.g. the ones you use in most projects, installed globally ... Other things would go in local virtualenv-folders

Non-conda tools

- [pipx](https://pypi.org/project/pipx/) is a pip-like tool that creates global virtual environments.
- [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) traditionally makes virtual environments per project, but thankfully @jwodder's answer explains how to use global packages.
- [virtualenv-wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper/) facilitates global virtualenvs.

conda

However, if you want to stay with conda, you can try the following:

A. Make a working environment separate from your base environment, e.g. `workenv`.  Consider this your goto, "global" env to do a bulk of your daily work.

```sh
> conda create -n workenv python=3.7 numpy pandas matplotblib scipy
> activate workenv
(workenv)>
```

B. Test installations of uncommon pip packages (or weighty conda packages) within a [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40700039/how-can-you-clone-a-conda-environment-into-the-root-environment) of the working env

```sh
> conda create --name testenv --clone workenv
> activate testenv
(testenv)> pip install pint
```

Alternatively, make new environments with minimal packages using a `requirements.txt` file

C. Make a backup of dependencies into a `requirements.txt`-like file called `environment.yml` per virtualenv.  Optionally make a script to run this command per environment. See [docs](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment) on sharing/creating environment files.  Create environments in the future from this file:

```sh
> conda create --name testenv --file environment.yml
> activate testenv
(testenv)> conda list
```

*Publishing*

The packaging problem is an ongoing, separate issue that has gained traction with the advent of `pyproject.toml` file via [PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) (see related [blog post](https://snarky.ca/clarifying-pep-518/) by   author B. Cannon).  Packaging tools such as [`flit`](https://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [`poetry`](https://poetry.eustace.io/) have adopted this modern convention to make distributions and publish them to a server or packaging index (PyPI).  The `pyproject.toml` concept tries to move away from traditional `setup.py` files with specific dependence to `setuptools`.

*Dependencies*

Tools like [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [`poetry`](https://poetry.eustace.io/) have a unique modern approach to addressing the dependency problem via a "lock" file.  This file allows you to track and reproduce the state of your dependency graphs, something novel in the Python packaging world so far (see more on *Pipfile vs. setup.py* [here](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#pipfile-vs-setuppy)).  Moreover, there are claims that you can still use these tools in conjunction with conda, although I have not tested the extent of these claims.  The lock file isn't standardized yet, but according to core developer B. Canon in an [interview](https://testandcode.com/52?t=2012) on *The future of Python packaging*, (~33m) "I'd like to get us there."  (See Updates).

*Summary*

If you are working with any package from the scipy stack, use conda (*Recommended*):

- To conserve space, time and workflow issues use conda or miniconda.
- To resolve deploying applications or using a "lock" file on your dependencies, consider the following in conjunction with conda:

  - `pipenv`: use to deploy and make `Pipfile.lock`
  - `poetry`: use to deploy and make `poetry.lock`
- To publish a library on PyPI, consider:

  - `pipenv`: develop via `pipenv install -e.` and manually publish with [twine](https://pypi.org/project/twine/)
  - `flit`: automatically package and *publish
  - `poetry`: automatically package and *publish*

**See Also**

- conda [docs](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) on managing environment files.
- Podcast interview with B. Cannon discussing the general packaging problem, [`pyproject.toml`](https://testandcode.com/52?t=516), [lock files](https://testandcode.com/52?t=2012) and [tools](https://testandcode.com/52?t=1732).
- Podcast interview with K. Reitz discussing packaging [tools](https://talkpython.fm/episodes/embed_details/208) (`pipenv` vs. `pip`, 37m) and dev environment.

**Updates**:

- A [new dependency resolver](https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2020/11/pip-20-3-new-resolver.html) is shipped with pip 21.0.
- [PEP 665](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0665/) proposes a standardized lock-file (c. 2021)

Comment: This is what I was looking for, many thanks! My initial question was indeed pretty unspecific, but you managed to address my key problems. The hints to `workenv`, the explanation for `pyproject.toml` and the background for `pipenv`/`poetry` dependency graphs are new to me, I'll give it a try!

Comment: No problem.  I'd encourage to take a look at conda channels.  There are many many packages that the community has created and are available along with the default packages in conda.  Also, the mentioned interview gives a good take on the state of the art.  Good luck.

Comment: I've update my question above with a brief report. Really happy I took the step to conda, thanks!

Comment: This is an excellent post that addresses some of my open questions.  GREAT explanation of facts from a seasoned developer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

> I was wondering if there is an approach to have some packages, e.g. the ones you use in most projects, installed globally ... Other things would go in local virtualenv-folders

Yes, virtualenv supports this.  Install the globally-needed packages globally, and then, whenever you create a virtualenv, supply the [`--system-site-packages`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/#the-system-site-packages-option) option so that the resulting virtualenv will still be able to use globally-installed packages.  When using tox, you can set this option in the created virtualenvs by including [`sitepackages=true`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-sitepackages) in the appropriate `[testenv]` section(s).

Comment: Wow, thanks! This seems exactly what I need. Do you know if this also works with conda virtual environments? I also need to test whether this works with cx_freeze for compiling everything in *.exe for windows users.

Comment: @Alex: I have no experience with conda (or cx_freeze), so I can't answer that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test and report back here!

Comment: can we do this with pipenv?

Answer (score 3):

An update on my progress:

Conda package manager turned out to work better for me than pipenv for the following reasons:

- by default, global dependencies are available from within conda virtual envs
- it is faster than pipenv when installing/updating dependencies
- combining pip and conda is really not that problematic, for anything where a conda package is available, install with conda, if not, simply install with pip
- by using `environment.yml`, it is possible to have a environment and dependencies re-created on both linux and windows in seconds - environment.yml allows specifying pip and conda dependencies separately (e.g. this solves the above problems with Fiona, Shapely, GDal etc. in Windows, by using conda versions)
- conda solves most of the difficulties of maintaining packages/dependencies across platforms (e.g. linux, mac, win)
- it was no problem to have conda (e.g. miniconda) installed side-by-side to an independent python install and use conda through `conda run`
- if environments.yml is missing, it is possible to create an env from requirements.txt (`conda create -n new environment --file requirements.txt`)

Unfortunately, the process of creating the `environment.yml` seems not really described consistently anywhere. After a while, I realized that the automatically created file (`conda env export environment.yml`) [should be manually edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280638/how-to-share-conda-environments-across-platforms) to contain the least possible list of dependencies (and let conda solve the rest on install). Otherwise, the environment.yml will be not cross-system compatible.

Anyway, this workflow solves most of my problems described above and I am kind of happy that I don't need to use pipenv or virtualenv anymore.

There're still some drawbacks,

1. One needs to maintain dependencies in multiple files:

   - setup.py
   - environment.yml
2. It is not possible to execute a program directly (e.g. with a shortcut) in its environment, e.g. this works without problems with `pipenv run`, but:

   - `conda run` will not automatically `source activate env`
   - this is an [open issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2379) and may be solved sometime
3. cx_freeze will not correctly include global dependencies from outside conda env
4. conda will be difficult if you need dependencies that require compilation (e.g. C-Extensions, etc.), see below or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157575/what-to-do-when-pip-conda-overlap)

Comment: I would urge caution using pip with anaconda. Just because a package isn't available through conda now, doesn't mean it will always be unavailable. You will run into problems if conda tries to install a package that pip has already installed. This could be especially confusing if the problematic package is indirectly reinstalled as the dependency of another package.

Comment: What do you suggest if a package is not available in conda, but is needed as a dependency?

Comment: First, raise an issue on https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues If that isn't fast enough for you then don't use anaconda. If you have to use anaconda because of a non-python dependency then you have no choice but to use pip. But just be aware that in the future your installation might break (perhaps silently) and that you'll either get undefined behaviour or you might have to reinstall anaconda and your packages from scratch.

Comment: An example of what could go wrong: You need `libA` v2.0, but only v1.0 is available via conda, so you install using pip. You then install `libB` v3.0 via conda. `libB` depends on `libA` v1.0 and so conda installs that over v2.0. You write your code depending on features in `libA` v2.0, but in reality it will use `libA` v1.0. Best case scenario your program crashes. Worst case: it continues, but with erroneous results. So you'll need to manually check your package dependencies in both pip and conda to make sure they don't have conflicts.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense and I think I just ran into this issue with numpy and mkl. Anyway, I have lots of `non-python dependencies` (data science), so there's almost no way around anaconda. I'll look into the issue reporting, thanks!

Comment: I added the problem with conda and C-Extensions to the list above

Comment: Guys, don't confuse conda with Anaconda.  They are completely separate concerns.  I think the best way to help the data science community is for someone to build a conda-pip package converter package that reliably converts any pip package into a conda package for personal use, and then posts it to conda-forge for approval, so others can soon benefit from it.  This take perceived ownership away from Anaconda and places it on package developers.  Anaconda can help do QA and commercial support, but data science developers need to get into the habit of delivering conda versions of pip packages.

Comment: I agree, but the process to get conda-forge packages accepted is strained these days and can take weeks, if not months.

Answer (score 0):

> `Shapely`, `Fiona`, `GDAL`

I have had so many breakages (package + DLL dependency hell) from this pool of packages plus related ones like `cartopy`, that I conclude it is not so much a matter of tool choice, but a reliable way to define, preserve and reproduce a stable working environment. For Windows, it could just be a bunch of `conda create env` and `pip install` statements plus whatever wheels needed from Gohlke's website (this is a lifesaving resource but it being such a necessity for Windows-users even in 2023, is already a huge problem by itself).

Comment: Stick with `Shapely<1.8` for a while longer, until all other packages adapted to the drastic changes beyond 1.7.