# in Spyder ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'

Tags: python, plotly

New to python.  Not sure how to to add a module.

`import plotly.express as px`

Error:

`ipdb> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'`

What steps are need to have this module recognised?

Comment: Did you check `sys.path`?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, both under *Windows* and under *MacOSX*, is using *Anaconda* for all *Python* apps.  This post also advises to use *Anaconda*:
[Python dependency hell: A compromise between virtualenv and global dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475042/python-dependency-hell-a-compromise-between-virtualenv-and-global-dependencies)

I also found this article to be useful:
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-spyder

These are the steps I took.

- Install *Anaconda*:
  https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/
- Under *Windows*, open the *Anaconda* cmd prompt from the *Anaconda Navigator*.  Under *MacOSX*, just open the cmd prompt.
- In the cmd prompt, install *plotly* with this command:

  ```
    conda install plotly
  ```

  This installs *plotly* in the *Anaconda* environment.
- Launch *Spyder* from the *Anaconda Navigator*.  **Always launch *Spyder* from the *Anaconda Navigator*, to make sure you're running the copy of *Spyder* from the *Anaconda* environment.**
- In a Python script, load *plotly*:

  ```
    import plotly as py
  ```

After that you should be good to go with *plotly*.