# versioneer installed, but pip install still gives ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pip

I have the `versioneer` module installed in my environment, as confirmed by running `python -m versioneer --version`.  Yet when I `pip install cartopy`, I still get a `ModuleNotFoundError`, as shown below:

```
(GIS3) gholl@lce00:~> python -m versioneer --version
versioneer (installer) 0.18
(GIS3) gholl@lce00:~> python -V
Python 3.7.1
(GIS3) gholl@lce00:~> which python
/hpc/uhome/gholl/miniconda3/envs/GIS3/bin/python
(GIS3) gholl@lce00:~> which pip
/hpc/uhome/gholl/miniconda3/envs/GIS3/bin/pip
(GIS3) gholl@lce00:~> pip install cartopy
Collecting cartopy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/92/fe8838fa8158931906dfc4f16c5c1436b3dd2daf83592645b179581403ad/Cartopy-0.17.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  Complete output from command /hpc/uhome/gholl/miniconda3/envs/GIS3/bin/python /hpc/uhome/gholl/miniconda3/envs/GIS3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /hpc/gtmp/gholl/.jtmp.lce00.20190206.082115.24214/tmpmcze3ux9:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/hpc/uhome/gholl/miniconda3/envs/GIS3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 207, in <module>
      main()
    File "/hpc/uhome/gholl/miniconda3/envs/GIS3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 197, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/hpc/uhome/gholl/miniconda3/envs/GIS3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 54, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/lustre1/gtmp/gholl/.jtmp.lce00.20190206.082115.24214/pip-build-env-q2k4jnrs/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "/lustre1/gtmp/gholl/.jtmp.lce00.20190206.082115.24214/pip-build-env-q2k4jnrs/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 112, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "/lustre1/gtmp/gholl/.jtmp.lce00.20190206.082115.24214/pip-build-env-q2k4jnrs/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 126, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 36, in <module>
      import versioneer
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'versioneer'

  ----------------------------------------
Command "/hpc/uhome/gholl/miniconda3/envs/GIS3/bin/python /hpc/uhome/gholl/miniconda3/envs/GIS3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /hpc/gtmp/gholl/.jtmp.lce00.20190206.082115.24214/tmpmcze3ux9" failed with error code 1 in /lustre1/gtmp/gholl/.jtmp.lce00.20190206.082115.24214/pip-install-2q1hjb0u/cartopy
```

How can it be that the `versioneer` module is installed but `pip install cartopy` still fails to find it?

---

<sup>*(I'm aware I [should probably not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48168337/974555) pip install into a conda environment, but I am meanwhile debugging a problem where a complete `conda install` either wants to downgrade Python, or results in [undefined symbol](https://github.com/conda-forge/fiona-feedstock/issues/68) or [cannot open shared object file](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9449) errors, so this question does have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) aspect to it — however, I still have additional things to try for my Y)*</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a known issue with Cartopy 0.17.0, as referenced here: [Unable to install cartopy from pip on MacOSX #1270](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1270)

You can try `pip install cartopy==0.16.0` instead, or also try using `pip install --no-use-pep517 cartopy`.  Alternatively, this seems to be an issue with >= 0.19, so you can also try downgrading pip.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error, and [this](https://github.com/python-versioneer/python-versioneer/issues/193#issuecomment-604025248) solved it for me.

I think versioneer needs to be installed in the build environment, which I have to assume is separate from when you've installed it.