# Do pip and conda share environments?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I know there are a lot of questions already about confusion between pip and conda, and although the answer here [Practical difference between pip and conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610707/practical-difference-between-pip-and-conda) comes close to clearing it up for me, it doesn't quite.

I have python2 and python3 installed.

And I have Anaconda Navigator. And in Anaconda Navigator, I can see that I have one Environment called "base(root)".

(1) If I install a package using pip, is that the same as installing using pip3? In other words do both pip and pip3 have a common place where packages get installed?

(2) Similarly if I install a package using Anaconda Navigator, the post referred to above suggests that that package would be installed into the same place if I had installed with pip?

(3) Does pip have the same concept of an "Environment" that conda seems to?

(4) If I am using Visual Studio Code for python dev, do you need to specify an environment where it should look for packages?

Thank you,
Paul

Comment: you can use python's `virutualenv`.

Comment: depending on what your `pip`'s path is, it'll be identical to `pip3` or it might not.